# Expect exception when using JUnit Theory

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit, junit4

In JUnit 4 you can declare expected exception using `@Test(expected = SomeException.class)` annotation. However, when testing is done using Theories, `@Theory` annotation does not have *expected* property.

What is the best way to declare expected exception when testing Theories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer using [ExpectedException](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) [rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html):

```
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

<...>

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Theory
public void throwExceptionIfArgumentIsIllegal(Type type) throws Exception {
    assumeThat(type, equalTo(ILLEGAL));
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    //perform actions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use a normal `assert`.  You can use it on older versions of JUnit (before 4.9).

```
@Test
public void exceptionShouldIncludeAClearMessage() throws InvalidYearException {
    try {
        taxCalculator.calculateIncomeTax(50000, 2100);
        fail("calculateIncomeTax() should have thrown an exception.");
    } catch (InvalidYearException expected) {
        assertEquals(expected.getMessage(),
                     "No tax calculations available yet for the year 2100");
    }
}
```